# How do you make a Cursor object traverse down individual SQL database columns?

Tags: java, android, sql, arraylist

I am working with Android and what I'm dealing with is a database that stores a number of data points associated in each row, sorted by columns in a table. What I want to do is extract whole rows of data and assign them to elements in an ArrayList. The approach I am taking (which seems to be overcomplicating things) is targeting the whole table and attempting to traverse each column and assign the data point at each to a variable of the object (in the element of the ArrayList.

I'D PREFER that I would be able to pass through each row and assign the data (ints, Strings, doubles) to variables of the object in a specific element of the ArrayList, then as I went on to the next row, begin entering the associated data into a new element of the list. 
Here's what I have:

```
public Cursor getAssignments() {
    return getReadableDatabase().query(false, ASSIGNMENT_TABLE, COLUMN_TITLES, 
            null, null, null, null, " ORDER BY "+ASSIGNMENT_COLUMN_NAME, null);
}

public ArrayList<Inputted> getListOfAssignments () {
    Cursor c = getAssignments();
    ArrayList<Inputted> assignList = new ArrayList<Inputted>();
    //must return assignList... but how to traverse?!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use these method listed [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html), but I would expect that these are the ones you're looking for. First, get the count of columns. Then you  can iterate the columns...

```
int     getColumnCount()
    Return total number of columns
String  getColumnName(int columnIndex)
    Returns the column name at the given zero-based column index.
int     getType(int columnIndex)
    Returns data type of the given column's value.
String  getString(int columnIndex)
    Returns the value of the requested column as a String. 
    (The other types are available and documented at the above link)
```

Comment: I'm asking, rather, how to use those methods in iteration, and how to iterate at all.

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i <= getColumnCount(); i++)`

Comment: Thanks, I get the column name iteration, but I want the elements stored under columns in separate rows to be iterated, either across the row (preferably) or down the column.

Comment: First iterate all the columns. Then if `boolean moveToNext()`, do it again.